# how i get width of div and then animate with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem with select client area slides please review below link

[**Demo**](http://www.aeiintl.com/new/information-technology/)

right now here is 10 imgs but it just slide and show 6 images,

i want thumbnailscroller width to scroll untill images finished.

```
<div class="inner_right_main_tow thumbnailscroller">Content here</div>
```

and here is jquery code,

```
$(".carousel-next").click(function(){
     $(this).parents(".thumbnailscroller").find("ul").animate({left: '-710px'});
});

$(".carousel-previous").click(function(){
     $(this).parents(".thumbnailscroller").find("ul").animate({left: '0'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you give it a fixed location to scroll to `-710px`

You need to make this dynamic with `-=710px`. This means that each time you click it will move 710 pixels to the left.

```
$(".carousel-next").click(function(){
     $(this).parents(".thumbnailscroller").find("ul").animate({left: '-=710px'});
});
```

But now you need to handle the when to stop..

---

*Update* to handle stopping (*gets more complicated*)

I would change the CSS to make it easier..

**CSS fixes**

- Remove the `9999px` from the `.carousel` rule.
- For the `.thumbnailscroller .carousel ul` add

  ```
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  ```
- and for the `.inner_right_main_tow li` remove the `float:left` and add

  ```
  display:inline-block;
  ```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var ul = $('.thumbnailscroller').find('ul'),
        step = ul.closest('.thumbnailscroller').width(),
        maxLoc = step - ul.width();

    $(".carousel-next").click(function(){
        var animated = ul.is(':animated'),
            currentLoc = parseInt(ul.css('left'),10),
            nextPos = Math.max(maxLoc, currentLoc -step); 

        if (!animated){
            ul.animate({left: nextPos});
        }
    });
    $(".carousel-previous").click(function(){
        var animated = ul.is(':animated'),
            currentLoc = parseInt(ul.css('left'),10),
            nextPos = Math.min(0, currentLoc +step); 

        if (!animated){
            ul.animate({left: nextPos});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to stop?

Comment: its working fine as i want...you are awesome Many Many Thanks dear :)

Comment: aka G. this is just working in firefox not in other browsers  :(

Comment: @shobi, set the `.thumbnailscroller .carousel ul` to have `left:0`. The problem is that without it some browsers return `auto` instead of a value, and the parsing the code does fails.

Comment: aka G. now its is not stopped after finishing images :( help me plz.

Comment: @Shobi, you have added `width:9999px` at the `ul`.. why ? remove it and also put back the `white-space:nowrap;` to it..

Comment: yeah its mine mistake sorry:( thanks for help again and again. :)